# Error: "body must be at least 30 characters" when editing an answer

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I tried to edit an answer of someone else and got this message:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 19

---

It's this answer: https://superuser.com/a/112134/151741

I wanted to change

> `Ctrl + Alt + D`

to

> `<kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd></kbd>`

---

Was the minimum character limit changed sometime? Would this mean that all answers that were created before can't be edited anymore?

Answer (score 1):

As of May 1, the minimum [character check was changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131300/133693)

> My trivial thought here would be to strip tags and white-spaces prior to measuring post length.

so yes, you're running into that check. There's no reason you *can't* edit - see the same post that I've [edited](https://superuser.com/a/112134/4377).